# Setting Authorization Header to .Net Web Service Client

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I know this has been asked a hundred times before, but I just can't get this working.  I have a .Net web service client that needs to connect to an external web service that does not return 401 challenge response.  I have to send the authentication header on the first call.  I have overridden the GetWebRequest method of the generated proxy class by creating a partial class in another file.  I have also added the method to the generated file to see if that makes a difference, but the code just does not get called.  This was originally a .Net 3.5 Web Service Project created in VS 2013, but I have tried changing the target framework to 4.0, 4.5 e.t.c. and that does not have any effect.

The code I am using:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "WSLDSD03_v1_webService_ValidationTicketCreation_Binder", Namespace = "http://llvap002d/WSLDSD03.v1.webService:ValidationTicketCreation")]
public partial class WSLDSD03_v1_webService_ValidationTicketCreation_Binder : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);

        string WSUID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WSUID"];
        string WSPWD = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WSPWD"];
        string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(WSUID + ":" + WSPWD));

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

        return request;
    }
}
```

Update: I have since found that after a clean solution and rebuild the method does in fact get called if I move it into the generated class.  It is the partial class in a separate file that appears to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a simple coding error.  I failed to notice that the namespace in the generated proxy file was like MyProject.WebReference, but in my separate file I used the main project namespace.